# Why am I losing my variables in NodeJS + MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
function getBlocks(docs){
        var jsonResults = docs;
        for(var i = 0; i < jsonResults.length; i++){
            console.log(jsonResults[i]); //Proper result
            database.Block.findOne({brand_id: docs[i]._brand[0]['_id'], timestamp: {$lte: new Date()}}, function(error, results){
                console.log(jsonResults[i]); //Undefined
                console.log(i); //Returns 2 twice (there's 2 documents)
                res.json(jsonResults);
            });
        }
    }
```

I'm knew to NodeJS so I know it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of NodeJS but I have no idea how I would go about fixing it.

**EDIT**: I've updated the code. I want to output the changed array AFTER the forEach is completed and I've appended the data.

```
function getBlocks(docs){
    var jsonResults = docs;
    jsonResults.forEach(function(doc, i){
        console.log(doc);
        database.Block.findOne({brand_id: docs[i]._brand[0]['_id'], timestamp: {$lte: new Date()}}, function(error, results){

            jsonResults[i]['test'] = results;
            console.log(jsonResults[i]['test']); //Has array test. Previous line worked.

        });
    });
    res.json(jsonResults); //Outputs unchanged array.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a classical scoping issue. When a callback inside `findOne` is called `i` already is the last index of the array. But functions create a separate scope (unlike code blocks) so try this:

```
function getBlocks(docs){
    var jsonResults = docs;
    jsonResults.forEach(function(doc, i) {
        console.log(doc); //Proper result
        database.Block.findOne({brand_id: doc._brand[0]['_id'], timestamp: {$lte: new Date()}}, function(error, results){
            console.log(doc);
            console.log(i);
            res.json(jsonResults);
        });
    });
}
```

**EDIT** The other problem is a bit different. It's a matter of synchronization. You have to wait until all asynchronous jobs finish what they do and then proceed. Have a look at [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). It's a very nice library which will help you achieve this in a clean and simple way. You can implement this mechanism on your though. Try something like this:

```
function getBlocks(docs){
    var jsonResults = docs,
        jobs = [];

    var finalize = function() {
        // here goes the final code
        res.json(jsonResults); //Outputs unchanged array.
    };

    jsonResults.forEach(function(doc, i){
        jobs.push(i); // add current job to the pool
        console.log(doc);
        database.Block.findOne({brand_id: docs[i]._brand[0]['_id'], timestamp: {$lte: new Date()}}, function(error, results){

            jsonResults[i]['test'] = results;
            console.log(jsonResults[i]['test']); //Has array test. Previous line worked.

            // remove current job from the pool
            var idx = jobs.indexOf(i);
            if (idx != -1) {
                jobs.splice(idx, 1);
            }
            // if no more jobs then finalize
            if (typeof jobs[0] === "undefined") {
                finalize();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: How would I preserve the value of i? Your code worked btw and has pushed me a step in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "preserve value of i"?

Comment: @user1426594 I've updated the code. Note that `.forEach` **is not** asynchronous, but `.findOne` is. Synchronizing asynchronous jobs might be tricky and I really advice looking at async.js (link in the post), especially `async.parallel`.